# Free Dotnet MAUI better Datepicker

Tags: .net, maui

Im getting some really bad feedback regarding the stock dotnet maui datepicker.
The users do not understand it, is there a way of changing the interface to the older style like below?
[image]

Or is there a better calendar. Im aware of telerik etc...

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data picker in the Maui on the iOS is the style you want. But on the android, it's default style is calendar. If you want to show it as the style above. You can use the custom handler to do that:

Create the custom handler in the **\Platforms\Android**:

```
public class MyDatePickerHandler : DatePickerHandler
 {
     protected override DatePickerDialog CreateDatePickerDialog(int year, int month, int day)
     {
         var dialog = new DatePickerDialog(Context!,global::Android.Resource.Style.ThemeHoloLightDialog, (o, e) =>
         {
             if (VirtualView != null)
             {
                 VirtualView.Date = e.Date;
             }
         }, year, month, day);
         return dialog;
     }
 
 }
```

And use the handler in the mauiprogram.cs:

```
 .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
                {
                    fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
                    fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Semibold.ttf", "OpenSansSemibold");
                })
                .ConfigureMauiHandlers(handlers =>
                {
#if ANDROID
                   handlers.AddHandler(typeof(DatePicker), typeof(Platforms.Android.MyDatePickerHandler));
#endif
                });
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I wanted. Although im getting a warning on the handler. stating global::Android.Resource.Style.ThemeHoloLightDialog is obsolete

Comment: This is the spinner mode in the android is obsolete. @SteveParry